# `xinput` does not affect mose movement directions on a rotated display

Tags: x11, i3, xinput, xrandr

I'm trying to configure display rotation with the `xrandr` and transform mouse coordinate axis accordingly with the `xinput` in EndeavourOS with i3-wm v4.22 running on a VirtualBox 7.0.6. While the monitor rotation works perfectly, the transformation of mouse coordinate axis is not applied to mouse movements: the mouse keeps moving exactly the same as it was before the change. However, when I try to select something in the terminal, it is selected in a wrong place, not where the mouse pointer is. When I move the mouse up/down it is moved right/left in the rotated display preserving the initial configuration for the `normal` display position.

The commands I used

```
xrandr --output Virtual1 --rotate left # works correctly
xinput set-prop "VirtualBox mouse integration" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

How can I apply coordinate transformation to mouse movements on the rotated display? My problem is that the `xinput` command does not affect mouse movements at all (not the correct values of the transformation matrix).

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it's this prop and param? Try doing `xinput list-props` once to see if the coordinate transformation actually takes place.